# Clarification on the Properties of a Photon

Tags: optics, photons

If someone is standing in a room that absorbs all light (completely eliminating reflection) and a laser pointer is shone down on one of the walls would the person be able to see it?  The photon is being directed in a single direction and is not being reflected by any surface so how, if possible, would the eye be able to detect it?

Comment: You see something because the photons hit the retina of your eye.  If the photon which is in your vicinity but does not enter your eye, you won't notice it.

Comment: Are you asking if a single photon travels from point A to point B along a line and you are at point C which is not on that line between A and B, would you see the photon?  Answer: No.

Comment: @K7PEH that was what I was asking, thanks for the answer.

Comment: As a twist, if there was any dust in the air in the room, the photons may hit the dust before they hit the wall and scatter off that dust.

Answer (score 1):

### **NO** - **The human eye wont be able to detect it.**

```
As you said assuming a hypothetical situation in which a person 
is standing in a room whose walls somehow absorbs 100% light that 
falls on it.
```

Now if you are in such a room and you were to shine a laser on the wall the walls will absorb all the laser as laser is another form of light, so our eyes wont be able to detect it.

---

### **Why our eyes wont be able to detect it ?**

What ever we are able to see in daily life is because the receptors in our eyes pick up thee light or reflected photons from the surface of the object we are looking at. If there will be no photons reflecting from the surface of the object, there will be nothing to stimulate our receptors in the eye.

This is the reason we are not able to see in dark, because there is just not enough photons or none at all to reflect from the object we want to see for our eyes to pick them.

Since our hypothetical walls will absorb all the light or photon falling on it so it wont reflect any of it which will create similar situation as trying to look in dark. Shining a laser beam on it wont do anything as it will also get absorbed.

Answer (score 0):

The human eye would not see it. The most light-absorbing material known to man is black carbon (you can make this by burning sugar) at something like 92% absorbtion. It is black because the human eye does not detect the same number of photons reflecting off of it as in other things. An object, as you described, with 100% absorption would not reflect any photons to the human eye and thus, would, since it is the absence of color, be true black. One example of this is the universe with something like 98% absorption. It is important to remember that in most eye-detectable reflection, light is a wave, not a particle. I recommend you watch Spacetime PBS (on Youtube) for more info and for more physics!

Comment: [Vantablack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack) is actually a wee bit more absorbent than carbon black.  Carbon black was the go-to light absorbing material for a long time, but Vantablack absorbs 99.965% of light that strikes it.